# Using SELECT in this SQL statement isn't working

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

My table is organised like this:

[image]

With `key` as the primary field. The records shown are in the `renamed` table.

I need to get out the `original_name` by the key. The key coluimn is the primary key of the table.

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT original_name FROM `renamed` WHERE key='fb166'
```

However, it does not return any results. I have tried both through my PHP script and directly through phpMyAdmin and both return an empty result set.

Any help? :/

Comment: Could the value contain spaces?  E.g. `'fb166 '`?

Comment: If you have `WHERE key LIKE '%fb166%'`, do you get any results?

Comment: What's the SQL data type of the `key` field?

Comment: Bill, none of the keys contain spaces, that was my first guess. :) Sarah, I get an error in my SQL syntax. If I surround key with ', I get an empty result set.

Comment: Bryan, the key field is of type text.

Comment: I highly recommend not using TEXT keys.  Use VARCHAR keys instead.

Comment: I'll change the type now, thanks. :)

Comment: Whoops, I should have mentioned that `VARCHAR` requires a max length, such as `VARCHAR(50)`  It is variable length though (unlike `CHAR`), so it sill saves storage space like `TEXT` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in MySQL.  Have you tried:

```
SELECT original_name FROM `renamed` WHERE `key`='fb166'
```

Comment: Ah! That works. I forgot all about the possibility of reserved words. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT '|' || key || '|'
FROM renamed
WHERE key LIKE '%fb166%'
```

and check if you get a result and how the key looks like...

Do you get any results with the following?

```
SELECT * FROM renamed
```

Comment: That does bring back all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

1. The backticks are necessary as key is a keyword in mysql.
2. As suggested try with `WHERE`key`LIKE '%fb166%'` as you column is of type text it s probably you have some other char in it.
3. It s a bad idea to have a key with a type of text, you will not be able to make it a primary key or add an index to it.